# Typescript: Check if record property is undefined when using variable as key

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with a record inside it like this

```
interface Foo {
    bar: Record<string, barz>;
}
interface barz {
    j:string[]
}
```

Now I want to collect all the Js in a result array so I loop through the keys

```
const foo: Foo = {
    bar: {
      test: {
        j: ['value']
      }
    }
  };  

let result: string[] = [];
  
for (const key of Object.keys(foo.bar)) {
  // Key should be 'test'
  if (foo.bar[key]) {
      result.push(...foo.bar[key].j);
  }
}
```

Now it tells me that the `foo.bar[key]` could be undefined even though I check with the if. How do I make typescript happy without using `//@ts-ignore`?

Edit: in my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@src": ["src/index.ts"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/unknown",
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "newLine": "LF"
  },
```

Comment: "*Now it tells me that the foo.bar[key] could be undefined even though I check with the if.*" [the error message that I see](https://tsplay.dev/NVn9ZN) is `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ test: { j: string[]; }; }'`

Comment: @VLAZ sorry forgot to type the foo variable now you should get the error

Comment: [Now I do not see an error](https://tsplay.dev/Woq9aN)

Comment: It's wierd because that is the behaviour you would expect. But trying to compile it I get the error. I use the newest version of Typescript. I added my compiler options maybe its because something in there?

Comment: Bingo! It's because of `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFzIBKEC6UAJgDwDOYUoA5gDSnkAvAHwBuAgF8CoSLEQoyUATgLFkAKwrtOILgG0AuhIIF6IdshiYqGLAF5lhYgqp5HqyOxcrVxDcl0A5ABucAA2AK4QAYZuxJKx8UTiIkTG+KEQYMhQEKzhoWBUWtwGyPYGYo4EllDIABSm5gDWEACeyOgwyADyJGp0YAB0La2sdZbogwoAlNMORAD0C8gA0m3IrAAW6PmMpCgBHmAB3sBd45hT5Loj+nOuPtm5+UMADuFbdYPfE1dQN219IM1NNKkkjPggA)

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ!